# iOS Facebook sdk 3.14 - can't get friends list anymore?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I'm using the newest Facebook SDK and it seems I can't get the friends list at all.

I tried using the Graph API by calling /me/friends and by using the requestForMyFriends but none of them returned anything no matter which permissions I asked for.

Is it because 3.14 is limiting only to friends using the application or is it a different way to get the friends list after all?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API for friends list returns nil on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861365/facebook-graph-api-for-friends-list-returns-nil-on-ios)

Answer (score 6):

Facebook SDK 3.14 ([changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x/)) targets v2.0 of the Graph API, which doesn't allow you to get the user's friends anymore (you will only get the friends who are using your app).